# How can I PIVOT TABLE Or CrossTab By Datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot, crosstab

I need crosstab or pivot table By select Datetime.

**Table filesTA**

```
EmpNo     ChkDate                    ChkIn
00001     2012-10-10 00:00:00.000    2012-10-10 07:22:00.000
00002     2012-10-10 00:00:00.000    2012-10-10 07:30:00.000
00001     2012-10-11 00:00:00.000    2012-10-11 07:13:00.000
00002     2012-10-11 00:00:00.000    2012-10-11 07:34:00.000
00001     2012-10-12 00:00:00.000    2012-10-12 07:54:00.000
00002     2012-10-12 00:00:00.000    2012-10-12 07:18:00.000
```

I have tried following

```
SELECT tf.EmpNo,tf.ChkDate,tf.ChkIn
FROM (SELECT EmpNo,ChkDate,ChkIn
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpNo ORDER BY ChkDate) as tfNum
        FROM filesTA) AS tf
    PIVOT(MIN(ChkDate) FOR tfNum IN ('2012-10-10'))
WHERE tf.ChkDate Between '2012-10-10' and '2012-10-12'
```

But getting following error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility
level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature.
See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.
```

**Desired Output:**

```
EmpNo     10     11     12
00001     07:22  07:13  07:54
00002     07:30  07:34  07:18
```

I'm beginning learn pivot and crosstab. please help me to get my query working.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you running?  Compatibility level error would indicate you need to update the database compat level to at least 9 (2005)...

Comment: I'm Runnings SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: You have not accepted/commented on bluefeet's answer. It is giving your desired output. Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not able to use the `PIVOT` function, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select empno,
  max(case when datepart(d, chkdate) = 10 
        then convert(char(5), ChkIn, 108) end) [10],
  max(case when datepart(d, chkdate) = 11 
        then convert(char(5), ChkIn, 108) end) [11],
  max(case when datepart(d, chkdate) = 12
        then convert(char(5), ChkIn, 108) end) [12]
from filesTA
where ChkDate Between '2012-10-10' and '2012-10-12'
group by empno
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2310/5)

If you have access to `PIVOT`, then your syntax will be:

```
select empno, [10], [11], [12]
from
(
  select empno, datepart(d, chkdate) chkdate, 
    convert(char(5), ChkIn, 108) chkin
  from filesTA
) src
pivot
(
  max(chkin)
  for chkdate in ([10], [11], [12])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2310/11)

Answer (score 0):

IF you need to use PIVOT on databases with compatibility level below 90 it won't work.

Read this  [ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

After your modified DATABASE Compatibility Level your query will be look so

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT EmpNo, CAST(ChkIn AS time) AS ChkIn, DATEPART(mm, ChkDate) as mm_ChkDate
  FROM filesTA
  WHERE ChkDate Between '2012-10-10' and '2012-10-12'
  )
SELECT EmpNo, [10], [11], [12] FROM cte  
PIVOT(
MIN(ChkIn) FOR cte.mm_ChkDate IN ([10], [11], [12])) x
```